# History.js - Fallback mechanism

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pushstate, history.js

I am using [History.js framework](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

My issue is that in IE (7,8,9) everytime I use the

`History.replaceState({tab:2}, null, "?tab=2");`

The result I get from the browser is:

`http://localhost:3453/Accounts#Accounts/?tab=1&_suid=139369400073705596359121287533`

However according to their documentation it should be:

`http://localhost:3453/Accounts#?tab=1&_suid=139369400073705596359121287533`

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: From what I see it's working correctly, appending an near-full address of the current page after the hash. The second example is an example from a HTML5 Browser.

Comment: In an HTML5 browser the url would look like : http://localhost:3453/Accounts?tab=1 The hash and _suid is the fallback mechanism.

Comment: Apologies then! I'm not entirely sure what you're asking on the question, as it states here: they [shorten the URL](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/#whats-the-deal-with-the-suids-used-in-the-html4-states), Hence the the repeat of the 'Accounts'.

Comment: @MackieeE No problem mate. If the repeat it's by design, that's ok.